# Java IO: How to go to the next line after a certain amount of numbers have been written?

Tags: java

Hi I want to write an array to a file I can do this except I want to write the first 50 objects of the array on first line then move to the next line and write another 50 numbers and then the next line and so on.

at the moment I have this:

```
if (pause.save) {
        Formatter f;
        FileWriter fw;
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        File f2 = new File("docs/save.txt");

        FileReader r;
        BufferedReader r1;
        try{


            //f = new Formatter("docs/save.txt");

            f2.createNewFile();

            fw = new FileWriter(f2);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


            pw.println(mapwidth);
            pw.println(mapheight);

            for(int i = 0; i < overview.s.toArray().length; i ++){
                pw.println(overview.s.get(i).getID());
            }



        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!");
        }finally{

            pw.close();
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to do this for ages but cant figure it out.

Comment: use `PrintWriter.newLine()` to add a new line after writing 50 numbers. Also, use a `BufferedWriter`wrapped around your `Printwriter` to improve efficiency.

Comment: You could use the [modulo operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) to know whether you have printed 50 objects - in whicht case the remainder will be 0 - or not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
if (pause.save) {
        Formatter f;
        FileWriter fw;
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        File f2 = new File("docs/save.txt");

        FileReader r;
        BufferedReader r1;
        try{


            //f = new Formatter("docs/save.txt");

            f2.createNewFile();

            fw = new FileWriter(f2);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


            pw.println(mapwidth);
            pw.println(mapheight);

            for(int i = 0; i < overview.s.toArray().length; i ++){
                pw.print(overview.s.get(i).getID());
                if ((i + 1) % 50 == 0) {
                    pw.println();
                }
            }



        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!");
        }finally{

            pw.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user3929251 read this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in following way:-

```
for(int i = 0; i < overview.s.toArray().length; i ++){
      pw.println(overview.s.get(i).getID());
      if(i!=0&&i%50==0)
      //newline here
}
```